# Object.defineProperty относительно модуля

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть модуль содержащий методы, и не  содержащий не одного объявленного или инициализированной глобально переменной.
Есть механизм добавления свойств объекту `Object.defineProperty`.

Вопрос: можно ли(о правильности речь не  идет) механизм `Object.defineProperty` использовать для добавления свойств к самому  модулю (ведь при подключении модуля, он фактически становится объявленным объектом/переменной)?

Comment: никто так не делал, но есть подозрение, что объект описывающий модуль создается каждый раз при импорте. Следовательно, не получится расшаривать так какие-то св-ва

Comment: как вы хотите импортировать модуль? если что-нибудь типо `import a from 'a'`, тогда вы сможете что-то поменять

Comment: буду подключать  через require

Comment: на счет "ни кто так не делал", я  пот  попытался сделать и   nodejs ругнулся, нормальной  инфы я  не  нашел, вот и  решил уточнить здесь.

Comment: а что хотите получить?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html почитайте как устроены модули и в частности что такое module.exports

Comment: добавь пример кода что ты пытался делать и что ожидаешь в результате

Answer (score 0):

Для ES Modules я не знаю точно что там как устроено, но для commonjs вполне себе можете. Это один из способов защитить экспорт от изменения в другом модуле.

```js
// foo.js

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'bar', {
   get: () => 1,
   configurable: false
})
```